# Best way to Fetch connectionState from 1000's of devices - Azure IoTHub

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-eventhub, azure-iot-sdk, azure-iot-edge

Best way to Fetch `connectionState` from 1000's of devices. Currently there is not that much devices, but need an efficient solution.

Based on my understanding, currently I can fetch `connectionState` using

1. IotHub `Queries(select * from devices)`  or `registryManager.GetDevicesAsync(100);` -- these methods are not real time when querying for 1000's of devices, or wont be efficient when number of devices increase.
2. HeartBeat - I don't prefer this as this will overload quota when the number of devices is large which results in sending too many messages.
3. Operations Monitoring/Diagnostics Monitoring -- First one is good but its getting deprecated by October, 2018 and second one takes about 2 minutes to get message in eventhub(this latency I have tried myself and found out).

Please Suggest some ways and also correct me if I am wrong about any of the above.

Comment: Presently, the best way to obtain a device connectionState in the real-time manner is via the Operation Monitoring. This is valid like you mentioned in the 3. by 10/10/2018. After that, there is no a way to obtain a device connectionState close to the real-time (<10 seconds) in the push eventing manner. It will be nice, if this issue will be handled by the Event Grid.

Comment: @RomanKiss : Thank you for the answer. I have one more doubt, when a device get connected or disconnected, its get updated in Device Twin. But when i use route to send device twin notifications to EventHub and log it via Azure functions, the 'connectionState' property is missing; ie only desired, reported properties and some other system properties are present. Any way to get connectionState in it ?

Comment: It seems only solution back end has access to [twin tags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-csharp-csharp-twin-getstarted#create-the-service-app)(like ConnectionState). Still, need `registryManager` to get twin update data.

Answer (score 2):

ConnectionState field is only suggested to use during development and debugging not in the product solution.

And there is a limitation of retrieving connectionState because the [Maximum number of device identities returned in a single call is 1000](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/includes/iot-hub-limits.md).

If your IoT solution needs to know if a device is connected, you should implement the [heartbeat pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-identity-registry#device-heartbeat).

Since considering the overhead of heartbeat that you concerned, you can set a smaller timeout using this API: `DeviceClient.OperationTimeoutInMilliseconds`.

> This pattern achieves the same result as maintaining a device
>   connection state registry using the heartbeat pattern, while being
>   more efficient.

Comment: Can you show an example of how to implement heartbeat with DeviceClient.OperationTimeoutInMilliseconds?